# WPF How to catch ContextMenuClosing event

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I have the following XAML:

```
<Grid >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>            
        <local:DropDownButton 
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Width="18"
            Style="{StaticResource OrangeButton}"   
            ContextMenuClosing="colorPallete_ContextMenuClosing"
            x:Name="btnSelectColor">            
            <Polygon Points="0,0,5,4,10,0" Fill="Black"/>                                              
            <local:DropDownButton.DropDown>
                <ContextMenu StaysOpen="True" Name="colorPallete" ContextMenuClosing="colorPallete_ContextMenuClosing">
                    <MenuItem StaysOpenOnClick="True" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" ContextMenuClosing="colorPallete_ContextMenuClosing">
                        <MenuItem.Header>
                            <local:ColorPickerPopup x:Name="colorPicker" ContextMenuClosing="colorPallete_ContextMenuClosing"/>
                        </MenuItem.Header>                                                
                    </MenuItem>                                            
                </ContextMenu>                                        
            </local:DropDownButton.DropDown>
        </local:DropDownButton>            

        <Rectangle Width="17.5" Stroke="Black" Margin="0" 
                   Fill="{DynamicResource CheckerBrush}"/>            

        <Rectangle Width="17.5" Margin="0" Name="rtcColorPreview" />
        <TextBox Margin="2,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" 
                 Width="100" BorderThickness="0"                     
                 Text="{Binding ElementName=colorPicker, Mode=TwoWay,  Path=SelectedColorName}"/>

    </Grid>
```

The event handler colorPallete_ContextMenuClosing is not being called when ContextMenu labelled colrPallete is closing.  I cannot seem to figure out what is missing.

Please help!  TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.contextmenuclosing.aspx)...

> ContextMenu itself is a
>   FrameworkElement derived class, but
>   the ContextMenuClosing event will not
>   be raised by a context menu directly.
>   Instead, the event is raised from the
>   element that "owns" the context menu
>   as a property and is only raised when
>   a user attempts to close a context
>   menu in the UI.

You would need to adjust your code so that the handler is defined solely on the `DropDownButton` as you have done. If there is a nested `ContextMenu` then the nested `ContextMenu` will obviously raise the event.

```
<local:DropDownButton ContextMenuClosing="colorPallete_ContextMenuClosing">
        ...                             
</local:DropDownButton>
```

Using a `Button` it would look like this...

```
<Button ContextMenuClosing="ContextMenu_ContextMenuClosing">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
             <MenuItem Header="Go"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
 </Button>
```

..where when the `ContextMenu` containing the `MenuItem` closes; the event will be raised and the handler will be called.

Not certain what `DropDownButton` control you are using so I can't comment on what the `DropDown` property is and how you are nesting your `ContextMenu`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. DropDownButton.DropDown is just a proxy to FrameworkElement.ContextMenu.  After doing as you suggested, event handler is still not being called.

Comment: Is it your control? 3rd party?

Comment: Also remove your StaysOpen and StaysOpenOnClick values to widdle it down to bare bones