# Can't find the right handler for my desired event

Tags: c#, wpf, button, browser, bookmarks

I have a problem finding the right `Eventhandler` for my `ContextMenu`. Note that this isn't a `ContextMenuStrip`. I have declared the `ContextMenu` as follows:

```
public void button_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)//add a context menu to buttons
{
   Button button = sender as Button;
    menu = new ContextMenu();
    menu.Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Header = "Delete" });
    button.ContextMenu = menu;
    menu.Closed += button_DeleteButtonClicked;//find the right event

}
```

Example:

[http://puu.sh/6Jymf.jpg http://puu.sh/6Jymf.jpg](http://puu.sh/6Jymf.jpg)

And then, the handler (which now is wrong, .Closed fires the event when the menu is closed):

```
private void button_DeleteButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)//delete bookmark
{
    Button button = ((ContextMenu)sender).PlacementTarget as Button;
    string line_to_delete = button.ToString().Replace("System.Windows.Controls.Button: ", "");
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"bookmarks.txt");
    File.WriteAllText(@"bookmarks.txt", String.Empty);
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        if (lines[i] != line_to_delete)
        {
            using (StreamWriter wr = File.AppendText(@"bookmarks.txt"))
            {
                wr.WriteLine(lines[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically I'm looking for a handler that fires the event when "Delete" is pressed, not when the `ContextMenu` is closed. My guess is that my declare on the first piece of code is wrong but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: `"when "Closed" is pressed"` do you mean when `Delete` is pressed ?

Comment: You can refer the below link, which answers for your question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197226/wpf-how-to-catch-contextmenuclosing-event

Comment: You can refer the below link, which answers for your question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197226/wpf-how-to-catch-contextmenuclosing-event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to bind the `Click` event of the `MenuItem`. It's probably going to end up looking like this (I don't have the means of testing this code right now, but it should be close):

```
// (old) ...
menu.Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Header = "Delete" });
// ...

// (tweak to) ...
var deleteMenuItem = new MenuItem() { Header = "Delete" };
deleteMenuItem.Click += button_DeleteButtonClicked;
menu.Items.Add(deleteMenuItem);
// no need to bind menu.Close for this
// ...
```

Binding `ContextMenu.Close` is useful if you want to perform some code no matter what the user chose, but it doesn't look like it's useful to you in this particular scenario.

The handler method should also be adjusted, of course, to accomodate the different `sender`:

```
// ...
Button button = ((ContextMenu)((MenuItem)sender).Parent).PlacementTarget as Button;
// .SourceControl could also be a viable alternative to .PlacementTarget
// ...
```

Comment: That code gives me an exception error on the line `Button button = ((ContextMenu)sender).PlacementTarget as Button;`

Comment: The `sender` is now the `MenuItem`, not the `ContextMenu` (it probably has a `Parent` property to retrieve the menu itself, I can't recall it, will get back to amend the comment once I'm able to verify it)

Comment: But `MenuItem` does not have a definition for `.PlacementTarget` is there another way to get which button is actually right clicked on?