# How do I subscribe to context menu closing event in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have attempted various solutions, such as the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197226/wpf-how-to-catch-contextmenuclosing-event), which has the accepted answer of the following:

```
<Button ContextMenuClosing="ContextMenu_ContextMenuClosing">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
             <MenuItem Header="Go"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
 </Button>
```

However, after implementing the above solution, I have still been unsuccessful listening to the ContextMenuClosing event, no matter how it is closed (making a selection, clicking the parent button, clicking anywhere off the menu or button). Below is my code, what am I doing wrong?

TestPage.xaml

```
<Page x:Class="MyProject.pages.TestPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MIMOUI.pages"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="300"
    Title="TestPage">

    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="myMenuButton" 
            Width="140" 
            Height="100" 
            Click="myMenuButton_Click"
            ContextMenuClosing="myMenuButton_ContextMenuClosing"
            Background="NavajoWhite" 
            Foreground="BurlyWood">

            <Button.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu x:Name="myMenuButton_ContextMenu" Width="250">
                    <MenuItem x:Name="myTaskMenuButton" Header="TASKS" />
                    <MenuItem x:Name="myTransactionButton" Header="TRANSACTION" />
                    <MenuItem x:Name="mySetupMenuButton" Header="SETUP" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </Button.ContextMenu>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

TestPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MyProject.pages {
    public partial class TestPage : Page {
        public TestPage() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void myMenuButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            (sender as Button).ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
        }

        public void myMenuButton_ContextMenuClosing(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine("intercepted!!!!");
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reasons unknown to me `ContextMenuClosing` seems not to be triggered when it was opened by your `Click` code. If you would open `ContextMenu` by right-click on your button event is triggered as expected. As a workaround you can use [`ContextMenu.Closed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.closed(v=vs.110).aspx) event which seems to be called in both cases

```
<Button x:Name="myMenuButton" Click="myMenuButton_Click" ...>
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu ... Closed="myMenuButton_ContextMenu_Closed">
            <MenuItem x:Name="myTaskMenuButton" Header="TASKS" />
            <MenuItem x:Name="myTransactionButton" Header="TRANSACTION" />
            <MenuItem x:Name="mySetupMenuButton" Header="SETUP" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

and in your code

```
private void myMenuButton_ContextMenu_Closed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("myMenuButton_ContextMenu_Closed");
}
```

the only difference seems to be that you cannot stop `ContextMenu` from closing as you would be able to in `ContextMenuClosing` event

Comment: I've got the same result, just using MessageBox() instead of Console. It seems your've found the right solution. Best regards

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately, I forgot to mention a large part of my problem. I need to intercept the closing event and stop it from happening, which is why I am setting e.Handled to true. Perhaps in the Closed event I can simply reopen the context menu, though, so capturing the event has still won me half the battle.